# Storing different kinds of enums in same vector - C++

Tags: c++, vector, enums

In my code, I have a structure like this:

```
enum myEnum{ e1, e2, e3};

std::vector myVector<myEnum>;

...

myVector.push_back(e1);
...
myVector.push_back(e2);
...
```

What I need to do is, I have to define two other enums like

```
enum myEnum2{ e4, e5, e6};
enum myEnum3{ e7, e8, e9};
```

and I have to find a way to store all these three enums in the same vector letting me use this vector like:

```
myVector.push_back(e1); //element of myEnum
...
myVector.push_back(e4); //element of myEnum2
...
```

My resulting software is a middleware and I will push back the elements of only one type of enum in a single runtime.

Basically what I want to achieve is make my vector capable of store three different types of enums inside, but the name of the vector will not change. Why I want this? Because there is a flow separation in the code and based on the seperation I don't know which enum will be needed at the beginning of each runtime.

Is this possible, and if so how I can I achieve this?

Edit: Thank you all for attention and answers, sorry I forgot to give an important detail. Enumerations in my working code are not editable. They are generated by a framework and I'm not allowed to touch them.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: By creating a tagged union and storing *that* in the vector, assuming the type is important to you. You can also use `boost::variant`

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use any 3rd pary library.

Comment: I feel like you are not giving us enough info to go on. If you only use one type of enum, decided at run time, then perhaps all the code using those enums should be encapsulated to make the concrete enum type immaterial.

Comment: I tried to give as much detail as I could. You can kindly let me know any further detail needed.

Comment: This feels now like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). The fact you end up with only one enum type at run time, implies there is an abstraction to be made, which you aren't making. But you haven't given enough information to clearly help you define it.

Comment: I also feel like there should be an abstraction to be made but, the custom framework my company uses and the cyber security things does not give me a huge playground. I inserted the parameters which I am allowed to manipulate in the question.

Answer (score 4):

You could do this:

```
vector<variant<MyEnum1, MyEnum2>>
```

But since you say you will only have a single type during each run, better would be:

```
variant<vector<MyEnum1>, vector<MyEnum2>>
```

This is more efficient and more clearly expresses your actual requirements.  However, you could also go for the simpler:

```
vector<int>
```

And cast as needed.

If you want something maximally type-safe and not using C++17, you can implement it yourself:

```
struct EnumVector {
    enum Type { type1, type2 };
    EnumVector(Type type) : _type(type)
    void push_back(MyEnum1 val) {
        assert(_type == type1);
        _storage.push_back(val);
    }
    void push_back(MyEnum2 val) {
        assert(_type == type2);
        _storage.push_back(val);
    }
private:
    Type _type;
    std::vector<int> _storage;
};
```

Answer (score 4):

Each of those enumerators can be converted to an integer value, and that value can be stored. You'll also have to eliminate overlap in the values. So:

```
enum myEnum { e1, e2, e3 };
enum myEnum2 { e4 = e3 + 1, e5, e6 };
enum myEnum3 { e7 = e6 + 1, e8, e9 };

std::vector<int> myVector;
myVector.push_back((int)e1);
```

Of course, the details of converting the value and recovering it should be encapsulated in a class, and not exposed like the `push_back` call here.

Comment: Upvoted - I prefer they way you've written the `enum`s to my solution.

Comment: Shouldn't it be e4 = e3 +1? otherwise e4 will have the same value as e2...

Comment: Yes it should be. I've fixed that for @PeteBecker.

Comment: If changing values of the enum members is possible, probably the sanest solution in the long run

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to give that detail, I edited my question. Enumerations are generated by a framework and I cannot edit them.

Comment: You can still do this, but you have to map enumerators to integer values explicitly rather than in the definitions of the enumerators. So `push(myEnum2 e)` would be implemented as `myVector.push_back(e3 + 1 + e)`.

Answer (score 2):

The most type-safe approach is to declare a vector of C++17's `std::variant`s:

```
std::vector<std::variant<myEnum1, myEnum2, myEnum3>> myVector;
```

See [std::variant](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) for more information. Before C++17, Boost provides an [equivalent template](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/variant.html).

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible the way you have it.

For example `e1` and `e4`, and `e7` both have the same value so are indistinguishable.

If you can get away with writing

`enum myEnum2{ e4 = 3, e5, e6};`

and

`enum myEnum3{ e7 = 6, e8, e9};`

then at least then the enumerated values are all different and you could use a `std::vector<int>`. But this is not entirely satisfactory since then the `enum`s need to "know about" each other, if you get my meaning.

Otherwise you'll have to imbue a *type* into your each element that you push to the vector.